# How to change value in raster layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

I have created future temperature raster (tiff format) in ArcGIS. However I want all pixel's value to be multiply with 10 (constant value). I tried to use con tool and raster calculator in spatial analysis, but it didn't work or may be I set incorrect parameter.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't give an example of your data / screenshot or the like, it's tricky to see where you're going wrong. However, this should work with `raster calculator`. You only need a `con()`-statement, if you want to multiply parts of your data with the constant value. `con` is stands for "conditional" not "constant".

Try:
`[your raster dataset here] * 10`

Comment: Thank dru87, I am not sure about typing in con command. Is it look like this: con ("my raster layer" * 10, )

Comment: you probably don't need the `con`... or else you need to explain in more detail what you want to do.

Comment: My raster is temperature data. I want to multiply parts of my data with constant value (10) in order to further process with other model. However, I tried to use raster calculation, but it seems to not woking.

Comment: what part of your data do you want to multiply? please edit the question above and add all information so we can help you... we need to know at least what selection of data you want to multiply.